# Who is the girl that poisons Jiraiya in Naruto 140?

Tags: plot-explanation, naruto

When Naruto [went to Orochimaru's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Two_Heartbeats%3a_Kabuto%27s_Trap) base, Jiraiya is "entertained" by a female ninja that poisoned him.

There is no continuation except that Jiraiya suddenly shows up later on the back of a toad.

Who is that girl and how come Jiraiya defeats the poison?

Comment: are u sure its 140th episode?

Comment: I think it's around that.

Comment: Is it a filler episode? or is it part of Tsunade retrieval arc?

Comment: Sounds like you interwined episodes. I don't see jiraiya in the synopsis of the episode you listed. There is another episode where he gets drugged (not poisoned though)

Comment: episode 139 the girl is quite hot actually but nameless

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 instances in the main arc which resemble the plot element you listed, one is when Itachi returns to Konoha where he tries to place Jiraiya under Genjutsu before trying to corner naruto alone but I am sure that's not the one you're looking for.

The second one the more close solution is in "**Bringing Tsunade Back Arc**" where naruto and Jiraiya try to convince tsunade to return to konoha to heal Rock Lee and Sasuke (who eventually got hurt by Itachi in the earlier encounter i mentioned). Tsunade drugs Jiraiya before trying to confront orochimaru to kill him its because she didn't want jiraiya to involve in the fight. I think you might be aware that Jiraiya, Orochimaru, Tsunade were called the **Sannin** **(Legendary three**) because they were a team once.

The drug causes jiraiya not to mold chakra properly causing him to fight at half his strength and he still summons **Gamabunta** (Chief toad) in that fight. I think that's the episode you're looking for.

Comment: Oh i think that's filler arc I don't usually watch fillers. I will try to watch it today to see if she comes in main story arc.

Answer (score 1):

Her name was Kotohime. She was a Fuma clan kunoichi. Narutopedia does not say how Jiraiya defeated her or overcame her poison.